# How to format a RDD using regular expression then store it to mongoDB in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

The original data is just raw web log, aggregated using Flume and published using Kafka. Like:

```
60.175.130.12 - - [21/Apr/2018:20:46:35 +0800] "GET /wp-admin/edit.php HTTP/1.1" 200 13347 "http://.....php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1 Safari/605.1.15"
```

I want to use Spark Streaming to receive a batch of logs, then split it using a regular expression like this:

```
val regex = """^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+)\s?(\S+)?\s?(\S+)?" (\d{3}|-) (\d+|-)\s?"?([^"]*)"?\s?"?([^"]*)?"?$""".r
```

Split into a database-friendly form:

```
case class log(
            host: String,
            rfc931: String,
            username: String,
            data_time: String,
            req_method: String,
            req_url: String,
            req_protocol: String,
            statuscode: String,
            bytes: Int,
            referrer: String,
            user_agent: String)
```

Then simply append the batch into mongoDB.

But I got problems in splitting the batch:

```
  val lines = stream.flatMap{ batch =>
  batch.value().split("\n")
}
val records = lines.map { record =>
  val regex = """^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+)\s?(\S+)?\s?(\S+)?" (\d{3}|-) (\d+|-)\s?"?([^"]*)"?\s?"?([^"]*)?"?$""".r
  val matched = regex.findAllIn(record)
  log(matched.group(1), matched.group(2), matched.group(3), matched.group(4), matched.group(5), matched.group(6), matched.group(7), matched.group(8), matched.group(9).toInt, matched.group(10), matched.group(11))
}
records.foreachRDD{ record =>
  import db.implicits._
  val record_DF = record.toDF()
  record_DF.write.mode("append").mongo()
}
```

This is how I thought it should be implemented.
First split the stream into lines, then map every line using regex, split into log format, and finally write it to DB.

Program failed caused by 'No match available all the time', or similar issues about regex matching failure.

...

Just a beginner, help is needed..

Comment: Can you share sample data.. where it says no match available

Comment: sample data is shown above, and 'no match available' error is always present.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:373)
 at scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchIterator.start(Regex.scala:764)
 at scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchData$class.group(Regex.scala:617)
 at scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchIterator.group(Regex.scala:739)
 at main$$anonfun$2.apply(main.scala:80)
 at main$$anonfun$2.apply(main.scala:77)
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
 at .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after modifying:

```
 val records = lines.map { record =>
  val PATTERN = """^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+)\s?(\S+)?\s?(\S+)?" (\d{3}|-) (\d+|-)\s?"?([^"]*)"?\s?"?([^"]*)?"?$""".r
  val options = PATTERN.findFirstMatchIn(record)
  val matched = options.get
  log(matched.group(1), matched.group(2), matched.group(3), matched.group(4), matched.group(5), matched.group(6), matched.group(7), matched.group(8), matched.group(9).toInt, matched.group(10), matched.group(11))
}
records.print()
```

Comment: I am not able to convert this into DATAFRAME. can you help for the same